# PHP Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Attribute alt redefined

Tags: php, warnings, domdocument

I am running following code on CentOS

```
$roster = $utils->getContentCURL("http://exporter.nih.gov/ExPORTER_Catalog.aspx");
$docmp = new DOMDocument();
$docmp->loadHTML($roster);
```

it is giving me some warnings like

> PHP Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Attribute alt redefined

Any idea, how to get rid of it?

Comment: You can use [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) to hide the errors, and inspect them after the load with [libml_get_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php).

Answer (score 5):

As the [validation of the website tells you](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexporter.nih.gov%2FExPORTER_Catalog.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), there's several errors of `alt` defined twice. One example is on line 252:

```
<div align="center">
    <a 
        href="XMLData/final/RePORTER_PRJ_X_FY2013_088.zip" 
        title="Click here to download XML File format"
    >
        <img 
            src="images/xml_icon.gif" 
            alt="Click here to download XML format file" <!-- RIGHT THERE! -->
            width="41" 
            height="13" 
            border="0" 
            alt="" <!-- RIGHT THERE! -->
        />
    </a>
    <br/>
    <b>(~1 MB)</b>
</div>
```

If you own this website (do you?) then you should simply remove these (or maybe ask them to fix their website).

Answer (score 3):

Often, fixing invalid HTML code (for whatever reason - missing/duplicated attributes, not properly closed tags, etc.) is not possible and it is not practical frankly.

In this case you may want to use `libxml_use_internal_errors()` function to `true` before parsing the HTML with `DOMDocument`. This function will **prevent** the errors from being displayed and instead store them in an array, which you can then access and handle accordingly. Just call the function before instantiating of the `DOMDocument`:

```
 <?php
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Set to true to suppress errors
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($html); // Load your HTML string
 $errors = libxml_get_errors(); // Get any errors that occurred during parsing
```